# disclose the alert button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, I've added the alert box and try to close the box if the user clicks on disclose button. But I don't know why this `if` condition is not executed.
can anyone tells me where I did make a mistake?

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var button = document.querySelector(".close");
    var successMessage = document.querySelector(".messageStackSuccess");
    var messageStack = document.querySelector(".messageStackError");
    // console.log(successMessage.className);
    
    button.onclick = function () { 
        
        if (messageStack.className == "messageStackError") {
            messageStack.classList.add("displayNone");   
        }
        else if (successMessage.className == "messageStackSuccess") {
            successMessage.classList.add("displayNone");
        }
    };

};
```

Comment: post the corresponding html tags as well. Additionally, did you see if the button onclick works without the if?

Comment: Why don't you use the classList with `successMessage.classList.contains('messageStackSuccess)`? May the problem is related to that.

Comment: You can also use the `button.onclick = function(e) { e.target.classList.contains('messageStackSuccess')`.

Comment: @MerianosNikos i used this `contains` property. But in some pages, this script is not working and in console it did not send any error. I'm confused what's wrong with this script.